# Python - improve time needed for requesting an API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using the below code to call different methods from an API:

```
import requests
import json
from unidecode import unidecode
from datetime import datetime

temp_county = 'County'
temp_locality = 'Locality'

# Function - login

session = requests.Session()


def login():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }

    # User's credentials
    body_login = {
        'username': 'user',
        'password': 'pass'
    }

    # Make the login request and return the token
    request_url = requests.post(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/LoginUser', json=body_login, headers=header)

    # Parse the token and remove double quotes
    token = 'Bearer ' + request_url.text.strip('"')

    return token

# Get country code. Since it's a local product, the request will return only the code for RO


def countries():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': login(),
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Make the request and return the country code
    request_url = requests.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Countries', headers=header
    )

    countries_dictionary = request_url.json()

    for country in countries_dictionary:
        if country['Abbreviation'] == 'RO':
            countryId = str(country['CountryId'])

    return countryId


def counties():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': login(),
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Load the country id
    params = {
        'countryId': countries()
    }

    # Make the request and return the county code based on the city
    request_url = requests.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Counties', params=params, headers=header
    )

    counties_dictionary = request_url.json()

    # Parse the city description and transliterate it to ASCII

    county = unidecode(temp_county)

   # print(county)

    # Return the county code
    for countyName in counties_dictionary:
        if countyName['Name'] == county:
            countyId = str(countyName['CountyId'])

    return countyId


def localities():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': login(),
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Load the country id and county id
    params = {
        'countryId': countries(),
        'countyId': counties()
    }

    # Make the request and return the county code based on the city
    request_url = requests.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Localities', params=params, headers=header, stream=True
    )

    localities_dictionary = request_url.json()

    # Parse the city description and transliterate it to ASCII

    locality = unidecode(temp_locality)

    # print(county)

    # Return the locality code
    for localityName in localities_dictionary:
        if localityName['Name'] == locality:
            localityId = str(localityName['LocalityId'])

    return localityId


#
print(login())
print(countries())
print(counties())
print(localities())
```

The functions are working well, with no errors or something. Problem is that it require (in my opinion) lot of time to complete all functions and return what it has to return.

I have used `requests.Session()` in order to create one persistent session in order to save time but somehow is the same behavior.

I've monitored how much time is required and for instance, it takes about 5 - 6 seconds to complete:

```
print('Process start! ' + str(datetime.now()))

# here are all the functions

print('Process ended! ' + str(datetime.now()))
```

**Terminal response:**

```
Process start! 2019-10-18 13:26:09.796132
Bearer 8JCAOoSSevSpcNDydLHSAmZORL0RGgDXV110IUhxIRWABX0TNj
1
26
163
Process ended! 2019-10-18 13:26:14.663092
```

Is there any way to improve it?

**Modified code**

```
# Function - login

session = requests.Session()

print('Process start! ' + str(datetime.now()))


def login():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }

    # User's credentials
    body_login = {
        'username': 'user',
        'password': 'pass'
    }

    # Make the login request and return the token
    request_url = session.post(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/LoginUser', json=body_login, headers=header)

    # Parse the token and remove double quotes
    temp_token = 'Bearer ' + request_url.text.strip('"')

    return temp_token


token = login()

# Get country code. Since it's a local product, the request will return only the code for RO


def countries():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Make the request and return the country code
    request_url = session.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Countries', headers=header
    )

    countries_dictionary = request_url.json()

    for country in countries_dictionary:
        if country['Abbreviation'] == 'RO':
            countryId = str(country['CountryId'])

    return countryId


def counties():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Load the country id
    params = {
        'countryId': countries()
    }

    # Make the request and return the county code based on the city
    request_url = session.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Counties', params=params, headers=header
    )

    counties_dictionary = request_url.json()

    # Parse the city description and transliterate it to ASCII

    county = unidecode(temp_county)

   # print(county)

    # Return the county code
    for countyName in counties_dictionary:
        if countyName['Name'] == county:
            countyId = str(countyName['CountyId'])

    return countyId


def localities():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Load the country id and county id
    params = {
        'countryId': countries(),
        'countyId': counties()
    }

    # Make the request and return the county code based on the city

    request_url = session.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Localities', params=params, headers=header
    )

    localities_dictionary = request_url.json()

    # Parse the city description and transliterate it to ASCII

    locality = unidecode(temp_locality)

    # print(county)

    # Return the locality code
    for localityName in localities_dictionary:
        if localityName['Name'] == locality:
            localityId = str(localityName['LocalityId'])

    return localityId
```

Comment: Maybe [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It seems you are not actually using the session object you created. Use `session.post()` and `session.get()`  Also, you are calling `login()` inside every function. I don't know much about azure, but I believe you only need to log in once. Just save the token to a variable and reuse it.

Comment: @Mosheperez - it did improved the time to max. 3 seconds. But I know it can be better, right?

Comment: @cdrrr what exactly did you change? Did you try to save the token in a variable and reuse it? I'm sure the improvement will be more significant if you will. You can 
also try to do the same with the output of `countries()` and `counties()`.

Comment: @Mosheperez I've edited and paste the code with modifications.

Comment: @cdrrr I posted what I mean as answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call every function once, and reuse the output as parameter for the other functions:

```
import requests
import json
from unidecode import unidecode
from datetime import datetime

temp_county = 'County'
temp_locality = 'Locality'

session = requests.Session()

def login():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }

    # User's credentials
    body_login = {
        'username': 'user',
        'password': 'pass'
    }

    # Make the login request and return the token
    request_url = session.post(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/LoginUser', json=body_login, headers=header)

    # Parse the token and remove double quotes
    temp_token = 'Bearer ' + request_url.text.strip('"')

    return temp_token

# Get country code. Since it's a local product, the request will return only the code for RO

def countries(token):
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Make the request and return the country code
    request_url = session.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Countries', headers=header
    )

    countries_dictionary = request_url.json()

    for country in countries_dictionary:
        if country['Abbreviation'] == 'RO':
            countryId = str(country['CountryId'])

    return countryId


def counties(token, countryId):
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Load the country id
    params = {
        'countryId': countryId
    }

    # Make the request and return the county code based on the city
    request_url = session.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Counties', params=params, headers=header
    )

    counties_dictionary = request_url.json()

    # Parse the city description and transliterate it to ASCII

    county = unidecode(temp_county)

   # print(county)

    # Return the county code
    for countyName in counties_dictionary:
        if countyName['Name'] == county:
            countyId = str(countyName['CountyId'])

    return countyId


def localities(token, countryId, countyId):
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Load the country id and county id
    params = {
        'countryId': countryId,
        'countyId': countyId
    }

    # Make the request and return the county code based on the city

    request_url = session.get(
        'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/Localities', params=params, headers=header
    )

    localities_dictionary = request_url.json()

    # Parse the city description and transliterate it to ASCII

    locality = unidecode(temp_locality)

    # print(county)

    # Return the locality code
    for localityName in localities_dictionary:
        if localityName['Name'] == locality:
            localityId = str(localityName['LocalityId'])

    return localityId

token = login()
countryId = countries(token)
countyId = counties(token, countryId)
localityId = localities(token, countryId, countyId)
```

Comment: Now it's much faster, 1 - 2 seconds which of course depends on the communication with the server that cannot be controlled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the dictionary iterations in all your dictionaries, by using items dict method.

```
 for k , v in counties_dictionary.items():
        if k == 'Name':
            countyId = str(countyName['CountyId']) if v == locality else "Whatever you want"
```

Comment: It's not a dict, it's a list.